# How to re-validate all transactions on a Corda node

Tags: blockchain, corda

We use Corda Open Source 4.3 network with several nodes. One of the nodes is an observer node where all transactions are being sent from all nodes.

Is there a way at any given moment of time perform validation/verification of all transactions available on observer node? Or can it be doen on validating notary?

I understand that they might be validated upon receiving them, but I am interested in recursive on demand validation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `TransactionVerifierService` to verify a `LedgerTransaction` within a flow.

First, you would need a list of all available transactions with the node. You could get the list using the below code:

```
getServiceHub().getValidatedTransactions().track().getSnapshot()
```

This would return a list of `SignedTransaction`.

To verify this using `TransactionVerifierService` the SignedTransaction needs to be converted to `LedgerTransaction`. It could be done using the below code:

```
signedTransaction.toLedgerTransaction(getServiceHub());
```

Once you get the `LedgerTransaction` use the `TransactionVerifierService` to verify the transaction:

```
getServiceHub().getTransactionVerifierService().verify(ledgerTransaction);
```

Hope this helps!